# AngularJS directive causes issue with page layout

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have downloaded ace admin http://www.bootstraptemplates.net/ace-responsive-admin-template

Now I try to use it in my AngularJS project. The problem comes when I use parts of the template and separate it into custom directives. I have tried to reduce the code as much as possible and isolate the problem I am trying to describe and I have made a https://plnkr.co/edit/4Xdk9dSlTWl4rWap7zav?p=info plunker.

If you open page-content.html there is a

```
<sidebar></sidebar>
```

directive.

This directive causes the

```
<div class="main-content-inner">
```

to fall under it.

But when you copy the code from sidebar.html and replace the

```
<sidebar></sidebar>
```

directive with it you get the desired layout.

I have no idea how to deal with this behaviour.

Comment: After you run the code you have to resize it enough to see the sidebar.

Comment: Try adding replace:true, in the sidebar directive

Answer (score 0):

Give this a Try

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

    .directive("pageContent", function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: "page-content.html",

        };
    })

    .directive("sidebar", function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: "sidebar.html",
            replace:true,
        };
    });
```

Comment: This actually works on this example. But when I use it in my project where I have routing and in index.html <div ui-view></div> it does not help. And from doc: "replace: true is deprecated" and may lead to misbehaving.